# Update doc with $set if exists else insert whole NEW doc using Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to update documents using a $set in mongoose, but only want it to use the set if the document exists. Else i would like it to create a new document. The problem is that I need that whole document to be added, not just the fields mentioned in the $set. Is this possible in one query with mongoose?

Comment: Code example:
bulk.find({_id: id}).update({$set: { title: 'foo bar' }}).upsert(newDoc) ???

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert:true` option:

```
    MyModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set: {.....}}, { upsert:true }, function(err, doc){
    if (err){
        return res.send(500, { error: err })
    };
    return res.send("succesfully saved");
});
```

Comment: Dont think this helps, as i need to insert the whole document if the doc doesnt exist. In this case, it would upsert using the values put into the $set

Comment: But it possible to pass to `$set` the complete object.